# Creating Route53 Hosted zone fails with InvalidClientTokenId

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Details below, but at a high level I've had no issues building out resources in AWS GovCloud, particularly in the us-gov-wast-1 region. When I decided to add a resource for a private aws_route53_zone I get the below error:

`* aws_route53_zone.private: error creating Route53 Hosted Zone: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid. status code: 403, request id: a9124a21-8eba-11e9-8bbb-c59c842ad843`

Normally I would think this is due to incorrect IAM creds since it's a 403, but my creds are working fine for every other resource, even those that are in the same TF file. I even tried changing them but no luck. Anyone know what could be the cause of this and how I can get around it. Route53 is supposed to be available in GovCloud us-west.

### Terraform Version

Terraform v0.11.13

provider.aws v2.12.0

### Terraform Configuration Details

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-gov-west-1"
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
}

... Other VPC resources.

resource "aws_route53_zone" "private" {
  name = "my-domain.com"
  comment = "my-domain (preprod-gov) terraform"

  vpc = {
    vpc_id = "${module.preprod_gov_vpc.vpc_id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are they all using the same provider configuration? I'm not really sure anyone is going to be able to help you here with it being govcloud. You'd probably have more success raising an AWS support ticket. Also, please, please don't be using credentials like that. It's bad enough when people new to AWS on hobby projects do it. If you have access to govcloud you should know better.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Credentials like what though? Those secret and access key variables are for my IAM account and are completely hidden from source control. We use a seperate ldap flow to access the GovCloud account itself.

Comment: Did this get resolved? I am facing similar issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this problem out. The cached AWS Provider plugin within the /.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64 directory was an older version (2.12) and had not been updated since the initial build out of the environment months ago. Once we performed a terraform init -upgrade the plugin was upgraded to version current (2.52). After the upgrade, we no longer received the "InvalidClientTokenId" error.